# Get single hash value inside array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

I have an array of hashes:

```
array = [
      {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: [3]
      },
      {
        a: 1,
        b: 2,
        c: [3, 4, 5]
      },
    ]
```

and would like to target the value `3` inside the array value for the `c:` key in the first hash. I assume something would be added to `array[0]` to capture that specific value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Hash, `c: [3]` is syntax sugar for `:c => [3]`. So, to access the value `3`:

```
array[0][:c][0]
#=> 3
```